# Micro services with a MVC front-end in .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, microservices

I couldn't find any content on web on this topic. Most articles stop at calling APIs with Postman. I can't use Web MVC frameworks (Angular, React etc.) for the front-end of the application because of our organization policy. So I have to use .net core MVC for the front-end. First of all, is it a bad idea? From my research I think HttpClientFactory is the way to consume APIs/Services in the server side code of the front-end MVC. Apart from that, I will be consuming the APIs using jQuery ajax. Any other ways to call or utilize APIs in the front-end? Thanks in advance if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked at server side Blazor? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OpenId connect mechanism in your MVC website.
You can see real-world example in github from Microsoft

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Web/WebMVC

You can check out `Startup.cs` file for openid authentication example

Comment: I already found that repository, but thanks. It has what I was looking for.